# Concatenate in excel with special characters

Tags: excel, concatenation

This is my excel table

```
state      City Name    area type
GUJARAT    Abdasa       City
GUJARAT    Adalaj       City
GUJARAT    Ahwa         City
```

I want to create this(in the row next to area type of course)

```
('GUJARAT','Abdasa','City'),
```

For that I have tried following formulas

```
=CONCATENATE("('"+A2+"','"+B2+"','"+C2+"'),")
=CONCATENATE("('" & A2 & "','" & B2 & "','" & C2 & "'),")
```

I don't know much about Excel is this possible?

Comment: Your 2. formula is working, what's the problem with it?

Comment: When I used it this appered #Value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use both `CONCATENATE()` and `&` operator - they do the same thing.

If you use `&`, write:

```
="('" & A2 & "','" & B2 & "','" & C2 & "'),"
```

If `CONCATENATE()`, write:

```
=CONCATENATE("('",A2,"','",B2,"','",C2,"'),")
```